# Error when trying to push something in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

code

```
case 'setup':
    let serverSetup = ServerDoc.findOne({id: message.guild.id})

    if(serverSetup) return console.log(serverSetup)

    if(!serverSetup){
        let newServersetup = new ServerDoc({name: message.guild.name})
        newServersetup.save();
        console.log(newServersetup)
    }
```

error
https://pastecord.com/zutetugymo
because I couldn't paste here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you think is your error is actually the result of the `ServerDoc.findOne()`. Since you are not using `await` or `.then()` when you are finding a document from your collection, this is what you get when you use `.findOne()`. To actually get the data instead of this, you just have to change your code to this:

```js
case 'setup':
    let serverSetup = await ServerDoc.findOne({id: message.guild.id})
    if(serverSetup) return console.log(serverSetup)
    if(!serverSetup){
        let newServersetup = new ServerDoc({name: message.guild.name})
        newServersetup.save();
        console.log(newServersetup)
    }
```